# Magento echo shipping totals with tax and currency

Tags: magento

I have found this old piece of code, which seems to work just perfectly in Magento 1.6.2.
My problem is, that it is not showing the value with Tax, and it's showing the value as ex. 60.0000

Would it somehow be possible to get it to show with tax and as a currency?
Or maby just somehow (I've already tried this with no luck, no matter how I put together the if statement..) build an if statement so that if it's 60.000 then it will echo 75$ ?

```
$totals = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getTotals();
if(isset($totals['shipping']))
print $totals['shipping']->getData('value');
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To get your cart total (assuming that the customer is log in or enter the shipping info)

```
$cart = Mage::getModel('checkout/session')->getQuote();
echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($cart->getGrandTotal(),true,false);
```

To get Shipping amount

```
$shippingMethod = $cart->getShippingAddress();

echo Mage::helper('core')->currency($shippingMethod['shipping_amount'],true,false);
```

Source http://www.magentocommerce.com/boards/viewthread/278544/

Comment: This is not including tax in my case? Although it is a custom module overriding shipping

Answer (score 0):

I made this crude solution, it's ugly, but it's working, if there's any suggestions to minimize this then please come with suggestions :) .

```
<?php $fragt = Mage::getSingleton('checkout/session')->getQuote()->getShippingAddress()->getShippingAmount();
                                  if (($fragt >= 0) && ($fragt <= 60))
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 75 DKK  ');
                                  else
                                  if (($fragt >= 75) && ($fragt <= 78))
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 95 DKK  ');
                                  else
                                  if (($fragt >= 79) && ($fragt <= 99)) 
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 100 DKK  ');
                                  else 
                                  if (($fragt >= 100) && ($fragt <= 110)) 
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 120 DKK  ');
                                  else 
                                  if (($fragt >= 120) && ($fragt <= 151))
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 150 DKK  ');
                                  else
                                  if (($fragt >= 200) && ($fragt <= 301)) 
                                  echo $this->__('Fragt: 300 DKK  ');
                                  ?> 
                                  </span>
```